# Is there any way to make a class function only callable from another class function?

Tags: c++, class, oop, public

I'm developing a little 2D "renderer" which draws things with **parameters read from classes** on screen. The drawing action is being done by a big Renderer class. **So there is a data transform between ObjectParameters class and MainDrawing class.**
I use to declare a public function to make possible the call from MainDrawing. But it can also be called by its user, and make the class object **insecure**.

So is there any way to make the declared class function be **only** callable (however the way is public, private or protected) by another class?

```cpp
class ObjectParameters {
public:
    COORD position;
    int Width;
    int Height;
    COLORREF elemColor;
private:
    int _zIndex;
public:
    ObjectParameters();
    ~ObjectParameters();

    /* This line is the code which won't be called by the user, 
    /* but MainDrawing class needs it for setting the layers.
    /* I don't want to make it callable from user, 
    /* because it can occur errors. */
    void Set_ZIndex(int newValue);

};

class MainDrawing {
public:
    MainDrawing();
    ~MainDrawing();
    
    /* Here will change the object's z-index to order the draw sequence,
    /* so it calls the Set_ZIndex() function */
    void AddThingsToDraw(ObjectParameters& object);
private:
    /* OTHER CODES */
};
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `protected` or `public` inheritance? Or `friend` function declaration? Just an idea, I don't know these are your answer.

Comment: It's a little unclear what exactly you're asking for. Could you perhaps write some example calling code so we can see in what situations you would want the function to be accessible and in what situations you would want the function to be inaccessible?

Answer (score 2):

With the `friend` keyword: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend

```
// Forward declaration. So that A knows B exists, even though it's no been defined yet.
struct B;

struct A {
    protected: 
    void foo() {}

    friend B;
};

struct B {
    void bar(A& a) {
        a.foo();
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a; B b;
    b.bar(a);

    //a.foo(); Not allowed
}
```

Comment: I would call attention to the forward declaration `struct B;`. That lets `A` know that it'll have a friend struct named `B` without needing to know the full definition of `B`, which isn't provided until later in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the private function a private member of an embedded class, like this:

```
class MyOuterClass
{
public:
    class MyInnerClass
    {
private:
        void MyPrivateFunction () {}
    public:
        void MyPublicFuncton ()
        {
            MyPrivateFunction ();
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

what I got is that you want that inherited class cannot access the parent class variable. For that you can simply do is make the variable private and function public. and inherit class as protect so that only child class can access and use the function.
if you want code I can also help with that.
First method is by declaring it protected and inherit the class.

```
    class ObjectParameters {
    
        public:
    int Width;
    
    int Height;
    
        private:
    int _zIndex

;

    public:
   

     ObjectParameters();
~ObjectParameters();

    /* This line is the code which won't be called by the user,
    /* but MainDrawing class needs it for setting the layers.
    /* I don't want to make it callable from user,
    /* because it can occur errors. */
    protected:
   

     void Set_ZIndex(int newValue);

    };

    class MainDrawing:ObjectParameters {

    public:
MainDrawing();

~MainDrawing();

Set_ZIndex(5);
    /* Here will change the object's z-index to order the draw sequence,
    /* so it calls the Set_ZIndex() function */
    private:
    /* OTHER CODES */
    };
```

second method is declare the MainDrawing as friend in ObjectParameters

`friend class MainDrawing` and make funcation `Set_ZIndex()` private so only friend class can access it

Comment: Without code, this answer is difficult to understand.